# Why is for (var i = 100; i--;) {} so much slower (70%) than for (var i = 100; i-->0;) {} in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Here's the test: http://jsperf.com/forloopspeed

As you can see, the difference is huge in Firefox, present to a much lesser extent in Safari, and absent in Chrome and Opera.

The analogous thing happens with while loops too: http://jsperf.com/whileloopspeed

Comment: Are you sure you need to know why? You could just submit your finding to the firefox bugtracker, and enjoy the fix when it rolls out...

Comment: Fair enough. Just curious I guess.

Comment: Not really related but another strange one I came across recently: http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-jamie/3 why is Firefox over five times faster at accessing array elements by index than Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that checking whether `i` (a Number) is a falsy value is more computationally expensive than checking `true`/`false` (the result of the comparison).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the internal `ToBoolean()` that is performed on the result of the expression is a bit slower when being given a `number` as compared to being given a `boolean`.

[In this test](http://jsperf.com/forloopspeed/2) I get a difference in performance when converting to boolean from a boolean vs a number using `!!`.

Comment: Your test is interesting, but the difference is slight and seems similar across browsers, so I'm not sure how it could explain why Firefox behaves so differently from other browsers with respect to my initial test.

Comment: @zjmiller: Well my answer is certainly speculation. I don't imagine you'll get too many people here with that intimate a knowledge of the implementation to offer an exact reason. But who knows? I do think that filing a bug report with Mozilla will hold greater potential for resolving your curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like some issue specific to Jaegermonkey.  If I run the test under Tracemonkey, the effect disappears.

Filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=670493